# Formatting problem in latex , pseudo code

Tags: latex, pseudocode

I am writing a report for my thesis in latex, most of the report is complete, one of the things left is to write up the pseudo-code for the algorithm used. The inserted picture is the pseudo-code I am trying to write.
[Main Pseudo Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMVVs.png)

I want a little help in writing up the for loops and figuring out the formatting, This is what I have done:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}


\title{test}
\begin{document}

\maketitle


\begin{algorithm}
\caption{pseudo code}\label{alg:Pseudo code}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Define the maximum number of iteration.
\For {i = 1: N flies} 
\State x_i.fitness = f(x_i)   
    \EndFor  
\State x_s = argmax[f(x_i)], i \in {1,.....,N}
\State \For {i = 1:N and i \neq s}
        \State \For{d = 1:D dimensions}
        \If{U(0,1) < \triangle}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `\EndIf` and `\EndFor` are missing
- If you want to use math symbols like subscripts, `\in` or `\triangle` (shouldn't this rather be a delta?), you need to place them in math mode

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}


\title{test}
\begin{document}

\maketitle


\begin{algorithm}
\caption{pseudo code}\label{alg:Pseudo code}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Define the maximum number of iteration.
\For {i = 1: N flies} 
\State $x_i$.fitness = f($x_i$)   
    \EndFor{} i
\State $x_s$ = argmax[f($x_i$)], i $\in$ {1,.....,N}
\State \For {i = 1:N and i $\neq$ s}
        \State \For{d = 1:D dimensions}
        \If{U(0,1) $< \triangle$}
          Quack
        \Else
          Quack Quack
        \EndIf
        \EndFor{} d
\EndFor{} i
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahhh that's what I was missing, thank you, I was trying to get the formatting right so I  left a few lines out to correct the lines before moving on and thanks for the suggestion to use it in a math mode. Thanks again.